# Why doesn't this preg_replace code work?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following call to `preg_replace`:

```
$str = preg_replace('@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', 'mask.php?l='.en('$1'), $str);
```

And I'd like to know why won't `$1` be passed into my function correctly?

It says `$1..` and if I take away those single quotes around `$1` then the code doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry to elaborate a little if I output what was passed to en() function it just says $1.. like its not being treated php code before hand and passing the actual value.

Comment: What is the output of `en('$1')` ?

Comment: `$1` will be interpreted as the first selection group inside preg_replace, not outside it.
You might want to extract it whilst remembering its position and after modification putting it back.

Comment: just $1.. like it isnt passing the value from $1.. if i dont try to pass the $1 into a function i see the actual value just fine

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. What is your input, the output and expected output?

Comment: i'm tryin to get a function to fire in reg_replace on the $1 variable before it replaces the text..

Comment: Which still doesn't answer the question Halcyon asked twice already.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this:
$str = preg_replace_callback('@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', function($matches){
    return "mask.php?l=en({$matches[1]})";}, $str);
 
however it is not activating en function which basically just returns the string encoded for testing purposes:
function en($str) {
echo $str;
return base64_encode($str);
}

Comment: You can't use a function call inside a string. You have to do this: `return "mask.php?l=" . en($matches[1]);` in your `preg_replace_callback` above.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = preg_replace('@...@', 'mask.php?l='.en('$1'), $str);
```

The execution order here is:

1. `en('$1')` (yes, literally '$1')
2. concatenate the result of 1. with `'mask.php?l='`
3. call `preg_replace`...

You're looking for [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('@...@', function (array $match) {
    return 'mask.php?l=' . en($match[1]);
}, $str);
```